# How do you do you adjust Gregorian Calendar date so that it is 24, 48 and 78 hours before using HOUR_OF_DAY

Tags: java, time, gregorian-calendar

I am wanting to adjust 3 Gregorian Calendar dates in Java, with one to be 24 hours before, the other 48, hours before and last 78 hours before. I had been using Calendar.HOUR and changed this to Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY.

Since I did this my code stopped working.  I am comparing the adjusted dates with their original values using a method that uses date1.before(date2)  and date1.after(date2) to get a comparisonflag 
which can be 1 or 0 which I then use in my code.

I was wondering how to do the adjust the HOUR_OF_DAY in my dates to then achieve
the above.

Comment: 72 hours, or 78?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would have been nice. But if I understand the problem correctly:

From the javadoc of Calendar:

```
HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.
HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.
```

When adding/substracting hours from a date:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -24);
```

This should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now()             // Capture the current moment as seen through the lens of wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region, a time zone. Better to pass the expected/desired time zone as an optional argument.
             .minusHours( 24 )  // Do the math, get earlier moment.
```

## Do not use `Calendar`

The troublesome `Calendar` class and related date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Use that time zone when asking for the current moment to be captured as a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Subtract your target number of hours.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMinus24h = zdt.minusHours( 24 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtMinus48h = zdt.minusHours( 48 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtMinus72h = zdt.minusHours( 72 ) ;
```

Compare with `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods. Also, [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is implemented.

Alternatively, you can represent the number-of-hours-to-add as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 24 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEarlier = zdt.minus( d ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).